# Regular expression prints and invalid response

Tags: python, indentation

```
# Reading CSV
import csv
with open('A453_datafile_4_Mat 4 Data File.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print (row)

import re
email=input("What is your email")
password= input("What is your password")

with open('A453_datafile_4_Mat 4 Data File.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['email'])
        print(row['password'])

    pattern = (row['email'])    
    if re.match(pattern, email):
        print("Valid Email")
    else:
        print("Invalid Email")

    pattern= (row['password'])

    if re.match(pattern, password):
        print("Valid Password")
    else:
        print("Invalid Password")
```

**Output**

```
['email', 'password', 'firstname', 'secondname', 'street', 'city', 'pcode']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['ojones@coldmail.net', 'ocrabc', 'Oliver', 'Jones', '53 Vale House', 'Portsmouth', 'P03 2TD']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['asmith@ablealarms.net', 'alan123', 'Alan', 'Smith', '3 Porter Street', 'Cricklewood', 'HE3 4DH']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['rakhter@bluebell.org', 'raj45', 'Raj', 'Akhter', '12 Middleport Road', 'Cheltenham', 'CH4 5GH']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['hrdg4678@netwise.net', 'ha123', 'Jan', 'Pietersson', '56 Holde Street', 'Birmingham', 'B23 3RT']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['miguel5@bluebell.net', 'happy3', 'Miguel', 'Santos', '45 Vine Avenue', 'Oxford', 'OX7 3RF']
What is your emailojones@coldmail.net
What is your passwordalan123


ojones@coldmail.net
ocrabc


asmith@ablealarms.net
alan123


rakhter@bluebell.org
raj45


hrdg4678@netwise.net
ha123


miguel5@bluebell.net
happy3

Invalid Email
Invalid Password
```

When I input data contained in the csv file which I print out I get and Invalid Email and Invalid Password statement print however whenever I input the data from the last set it says that the data is vaild. I don't know what to do since I am still a beginner at python and I suspect it is something to do with me defining 2 patterns.

Comment: 1) Your indentation is problematic. Much code that uses `row` is outside of the loop that defines the `row` variable. I'm not sure if it's that way in your code or just in the question. 2) Why are you using regular expressions for this? It looks like you're trying to do equality testing, not pattern matching. Regular expressions are *pointless* for that. If I'm right, just test the strings for equality. 3) I'm confident you could find a way to shorten this. 4) This question as presented comes off largely as a code dump.

Comment: You never provide python a regex that specifies the *email format*.

Comment: OP is simply doing plain string-matching `email=input("What is your email")` against `row['email']`. That doesn't even need a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple indentation problem.
You need to indent all the lines doing matching and printing (from `pattern = (row['email'])` onwards):

```
for row in reader:
    print(row['email'])
    print(row['password'])
    # BUG! only the above two statements get executed for every row
    # BUG: so the final value of email = row['email'] for the last row!

# BUG: so since the following lines are unindented, they only get executed once,
# which is not what you want!
pattern = (row['email']) ...  
if pattern == email: # or pattern.index(email) >= 0
# ...
```